# How to add Vuex to an existing Vue 2.6.14 project

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I began developing a Vue project without Vuex. I recently realized that I need Vuex for the project. I have added Vuex with `npm` and I have populated a `store.js` file with Vuex boilerplate.

However, when I open the Chrome Vue development tools, it states: "No Vuex store detected."

[image: No Vuex store]

What additional configuration do I need to perform so that I can begin properly using Vuex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

In addition to adding a `store.js` file in the `src` directory, add the following lines to `main.js`:
[image]

Vue now appears to properly be recognizing the store.